# python regex for conditional (|) matching

Tags: python, regex

Looking for a python regex pattern.  Seems like it has to exist, but it has me stumped.

If I need to find an address, and the strings I am searching can be of the form

```
address_is_after_123
 - or -
123_address_is_before
```

Note, there could be more than two permutations, but I'm hoping a solution for two permutations could be extended to more.

I could simply create multiple regexes, but I'd ideally like a single regex.  The best I've got is:

```
m = re.match("(?:address_is_after_(\d+)|(\d+)_address_is_before)",text)
```

This works, but the I have to test whether m.group(1) or m.group(2) has the value.  Is there a way to write the regex so that if it matches I can grab the address without additional processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with lookarounds, provided that the length of the lookbehind (`"address_is_after_"`) is constant:

```
>>> m = re.search(r"(?<=address_is_after_)\d+|\d+(?=_address_is_before)",text)
>>> m.group(0)
'123'
```

Comment: Interesting.  I've been thinking in terms of re.match(), not re.search().  Bit of a paradigm shift!

Comment: This doesn't really have to do with `search` vs. `match`, only the latter is unable to match anywhere but at the start of the string, and since the number can be in the middle of the string, I need to use `search`. You can add anchors in the lookaround: `(?<=^address_is_after_)`

Comment: I guess what I mean is that I'm used to using match() and pulling out substrings using m.group(1 [or 2 or 3]).  I usually ignore group(0).  So using lookarounds and having group(0) be what I'm looking for seems backwords.  But since that is what it takes to solve the problem, I'm having to flip my way of thinking.  You are right, the flip is not do to match vs. search, it is do to the lookarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to test which group has the match. An unmatched group returns `None`, which is treated as false by `or`:

```
>>> for text in ["address_is_after_123", "123_address_is_before"]:
...             m = re.match("(?:address_is_after_(\d+)|(\d+)_address_is_before)",text)
...             print(m.group(1) or m.group(2))
...
123
123
```