# regex for checking conditional statement python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex that will find whether there is a condition statement into a code (which is in the form of string) or not. I have tried the following code but no luck and tried some relevant questions too.

**Code which will be checked:**

**There might be two types of if condition**

***One is:***

```
if True:
    print_content((weather_info('London')))
```

**Another one is:**

```
if (weather_info('London')):
    print('success')
```

*I have also tried some questions and they are as follows:*

[python regex for conditional (|) matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236924/python-regex-for-conditional-matching)

**Code for checking the conditional regex:**

```
if re.match(r'^if([A-Z][a-z]:)', code):
    self.conditional_step+=1
    print("condtional step:"+str(self.conditional_step))
```

Comment: Do you have some examples of `code` where it should match... your regex at the moment will only match things like: `ifAb:` (where "if" is at the start of the line and is followed by an uppercase letter then a lower case one followed by a colon).... that's probably not the logic you want...

Comment: I have a demo code which should be checked. I am attaching it to my question. Please have a look.

Comment: @SakhawatHossain not sure how that edit helps... you've just introduced two new functions with no information at all about what they do or how it relates to anything to do with regular expressions...

Comment: You should give an example where it should match. Then we can provide a `regex` otherwise we dont  reallly.

Comment: @JonClements, Well they are just other code and print_content() is a function. But my concern is to match the conditional statement.

Comment: This will do what you are expecting: ```r'if\s+[\w-]+'```.

Comment: @Onyambu. I just need to match the if section. Like if my code contains (if something:) then it should notify me.

Comment: then using `^\\s*if\\s.*:` should work in that case

Comment: @SakhawatHossain Are ***all*** the if-statements exactly like that? If they are, you don't need a regexp at all. I think you should show a longer example and explain what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonClements exactly.I wanted to make a regex that will check the line starts with the word "if" and ends with a ":" and it it won't match it will skip.

Comment: @SakhawatHossain, to avoid a long discussion - post an extended input samples. Otherwise, just go with `if code[:3] == "if " and code[-1] == ":"` or `startswith/endswith`

Comment: @ekhumoro. No, not all the conditions are not the same some may contain  `if weather_info(london):`  and some may contain `if True:`.These are the only two types of the statement can happen in my case.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest , ok i am updating my question.

Comment: @SakhawatHossain All you need to do is iterate over the lines using `for line in code.splitlines():` and then do `if line.startswith('if ') and line.endswith(':'):` to find the if-statements.

Comment: Why not use the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html) module for this?

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for your suggestion. But how do I match `if weather_info('London'):`  this string? Any idea?

Comment: @SakhawatHossain Once you've found the if-statemtents, you can do `if "weather_info" in line:` to see which kind it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks for everyone's co-operation.**

***I do get my job done by making three different regex.And i am adding those regex in the following and hope this might be helpful for someone else,***

```
regex_if_true = re.compile(r"^if\strue:|^if\sTrue:$", re.MULTILINE)
regex_if_false = re.compile(r"^if\sfalse|^if\sFalse:$", re.MULTILINE)
regex_service = re.compile(r"(if).*?:$", re.MULTILINE)
```